# Как перевести char в int, без изменения кодировки. Работа с StringBuffer

Tags: java, кодировка, char

Задача моего метода- преобразовать каждое число типа StringBuffer в массив int.

При попытке преобразовать каждый символ "9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 " с убранными пробелами я получаю результат: {57,56,55,54,53,52,51,50,49}

Как мне поместить в массив те же числа, что и в строке?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
StringBuffer strB = new StringBuffer("9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 ");
int arrInt=strBToArrInt(strB);
for(int i=0;i<arrInt.length;i++){System.out.print(arrInt[i]+" ");}
}//end main

int[] strBToArrInt(StringBuffer strBuff){
strBuff = new StringBuffer(strBuff.toString().replace(" ", ""));
int[] arrInt =new int[strBuff.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < arrInt.length; i++) {
            arrInt[i]=  Integer.valueOf(strBuff.charAt(0));//Я думаю -проблемма в кодировке.
    strBuff.deleteCharAt(0);//удаляю нулевой символ
}

    return arrInt;
}//end strBToArrInt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В твоём случае он возвращает ASCI-код символа. Тебе надо использовать метод [digit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit%28char,%20int%29). Замени

```
arrInt[i]=  Integer.valueOf(strBuff.charAt(0));
```

На

```
arrInt[i]=  Character.digit(strBuff.charAt(0), 10);
```

Но этот метод годен только для цифр. Если у тебя числа, то сначала надо разбить исходную строку на массив строк при помощи метода `split`.

```
String []stringsArray=strBuff.toString().trim().split("\\s+");
```

А потом пройтись и распарсить каждую строку как число

```
int[] arrInt =new int[stringsArray.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < stringsArray.length; i++) {
    arrInt[i]=  Integer.parseInt(stringsArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Конвертируйте строку в массив символов:

```
char[] = String.toCharArray();
```

Используйте `int[i] = Character.getNumericValue(char[i]);`. 
Конечно, в вашем случае используйте `charAt();`, при чем в одной строке можно конвертировать к `int`.